# Splitting single lines to represent two-way streets using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, line

I am working on a project using city road data. The data has every road in the city visualized as lines and with directional data stored in the attribute table (one-way to-from, one-way from-to, and all).

Is there a way to split the two-way lines into two separate one-way lines offset from one another but ending in the same point?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edges can contain routing direction for each edge, so no need to bifurcate. The reason for bifurcations that look like your topology, commonly used in routing software, are to encompass the presence of interior physical restrictions such as barrier with the median of in dual carriageways.. The routing aspect can be handled by interior and exterior turn restriction causing code running on the object model to represent the path of traffic at intersection segment features.